# Concurrently sending more than two request ActiveMQ queue in apache camel then it fails to respond

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

client side request:

```
public Message receive(String message, String queueName) {
    String text = null;
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(
            "tcp://10.0.0.0:61616");
    String userName = "smx";
    String password = "smx";
    Connection connection;
    Message response =null;
    try {
        connection = connectionFactory.createConnection(userName, password);
        connection.start();
        ((ActiveMQConnectionFactory) connectionFactory)
                .setDispatchAsync(false);
        Session session = connection.createSession(false,
                Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Queue destination = session.createQueue(queueName);
        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
        producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
        TextMessage textMessage = session.createTextMessage(message);
        Queue tempQueue = session.createQueue(queueName);
        textMessage.setJMSReplyTo(tempQueue);
        producer.send(textMessage);
        MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(tempQueue);
        response = consumer.receive();
        response.acknowledge();

        session.close();
        connection.close();
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return response;
}
```

server side:

```
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("activemq:queue:GET_QUEUE?disableReplyTo=true")
            .setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOut)
            .to("freemarker:Response.ftl")
            .inOnly("activemq:queue:GET_QUEUE");
}
```

the following thing i have already tried did not get results
1)activemq:queue:GET_QUEUE?disableReplyTo=true&concurrentConsumers=5

2)activemq:queue:GET_QUEUE?disableReplyTo=true&concurrentConsumers=1&maxConcurrentConsumers=5

3)activemq:queue:GET_QUEUE?disableReplyTo=true&useMessageIDAsCorrelationID=true&concurrentConsumers=5

4)activemq:queue:GET_QUEUE?disableReplyTo=true&useMessageIDAsCorrelationID=true&concurrentConsumers=5&asyncConsumer=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have disabled replyTo in Camel which you should not do, then remove the last inOnly as Camel will automatic send the message back to the reply to queue when the route is done.

Comment: tried your suggestion but same result synchronously 4 request sent to the queue only one response am getting back from queue.

Comment: thanks  with concurrentConsumer attribute added with your suggestion i got 4 request sent and 4 response but am getting mix and match response can you help me..